# How can i edit font-size and font-family option in css file using sed?

Tags: css, regex, linux, bash, sed

I try to edit css font-size and font-family option with sed command in ubuntu,
my css is:

```
stage {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

i use this command:

```
sed -i -e "/(stage\s*\{[\w\s:\-;\(\)#]*)(font-size\s*:\s*)([^\}])(|\})/20pt/" theme.css
```

it returns error about regex command. How can i edit font-family and font-size in "stage" using "sed"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i.bak '/^stage/,/}$/ s/font-size:.*/font-size: 20pt;/g' theme.css
```

It will do the replacement between the lines which begin with 'stage' and ends with '}'

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks, it works with my example, i want to use this command different theme files, so there is a problem with space, some themes use (dont use) space  after/before stage/fontsize. For exampler if i change css code like this "stage{" and "font-size : 20pt;" your answer doesnt work. EDIT: I add "\s*" my problem fixed. Thanks

Comment: The regex is not matching spaces, therefore should work. If you can give an a sample of the css file which is not working I may offer a better solution

Comment: i use this regex command for solution "/^stage\s*/,/}$/ s/font-family\s*:\s*.*/font-family: \"font name\";/g'". For example i change font-size like this "font-size    :   9pt;" or i change "stage{" like this "stage  {" By the way, i have problem in some themes, there isnt font-size or font-family, but i want to be.